# Questions about WDS and Boot/Install images

Tags: wds

Going through and trying to configure a new WDS server, and wanted to get some clarification on a couple things.

Is the boot image just a generic image that all clients will use, regardless if i'm installing a 32bit OS or 64bit OS, or even a different version OS, Win7 vs Win8?

Similarly for capturing an image, do I need a different image for each architecture/operating system?

Answer (score 1):

The boot image is just for pxe boot.  It is pxe architecture specific, not OS specific.  You do not need separate images for capture.